# How to statistically treat my data?

Tags: group-differences

Here's the situation.
I have 3 set-ups: A, B, and C

I want to measure 2 variables in all of them (pH and alcoholic content) over time

I want to know if the pH level or alcoholic content in A is significantly higher or lower than the one in B or C based on their time trends.

I don't want to look for an equation or anything. I just want to know if those parameters are generally higher when all time periods are considered.

pH is also not related to alcoholic content in any way.

Comment: And do you have multiple samples over the same timeline for each of A, B, and C?

Comment: Can you explain why pH is not related to alcohol content? It could be the case under suitable assumptions, but the first thing that occurred to me is that ethanol has a $pK_a \approx 16$ combined with the [Henderson-Hasselbalch approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation).

Comment: Hello everyone. I don't know what you mean by multiple samples but I will explain how I get my samples. 
There is a juice with alcohol in it. When I sample, I get three (2 mL) samples from the juice and get the alcoholic content for each. I then get the average of the three. That is what my data is for the alcoholic content.

As for the timeline, I do my sampling 1,2,3,4,6,8,10,15, and 20 hours after the process begins for all of the set-ups.

Comment: As for the relationship between pH and alcohol, the situation is like this. 

There are a series of reactors. I get the samples for the alcoholic content from the mixture before it passes through a reactor.

As for the pH level, I get samples from that after the the mixture passes through the reactors. The pH level is for a mixture containing a completely different substance.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of inconsistency between "based on their time trends" versus "when all time periods are considered." The first suggests that you want to know specifically how things change over time, the second that you don't care about changes over time so that perhaps some average over all times would do. Please edit the question to say more about which of those you care about, and to add the extra information you provided in comments. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Please add new information in comments as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked ....